# Simple_Form display validation error messages next to different input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a form that allows the user to search for existing records to populate an association.  Each "Booking" belongs to a "Customer".  So the form allows you type the customer's name, it does a search automatically, and you click the customer you want.  The input field you're typing into should display the customer's name, but for the form to work, I set the `customer_id` in a hidden input field.

I'm using the simple_form gem.  Does anybody know if I can display the validation errors for the `customer_id` next to the text input field that displays the customer's name?  The `customer_id` is required in the model, so I need the form to tell the user that if they leave it blank.

View code (simplified -- there's some JavaScript that handles searching when you type into the customer text box, and that sets the value in the hidden field to the customer's id when you make a selection):

```
<%= simple_form_for @booking do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :customer_id, id: "customer_id" %>
  <%= f.input :customer, required: true,
      input_html: { value: @booking.customer_name } %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I eventually found out about the `append` block in simple_form ([buried in a pull request](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/pull/531), not documented anywhere else that I could find).  Basically, you can use that to append whatever markup you want to your `f.input`.  I did the following, which is pretty hacky, but it does what I need it to do:

```
<%= f.input :customer, required: true,
    wrapper_html: { class: ("error" if @booking.errors[:customer_id].any?) } do %>
  <%= f.input_field :customer, value: @booking.customer_name %>
  <%= f.error :customer_id %>
<% end %>
```

First, I had to conditionally add the class "error" to the wrapper if there were any errors on the related field, then I used the `append` block to render out the input field, followed by the errors for the related field from the model.  Hope this helps someone in the future!